# Alias for array elements in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, class, alias

I have a system with more than 40 ODEs to solve, which normally can be done with some library like intel ODE. Due to the nature of this problem, these libraries only take arrays as parameter. In this way I have to put all the states of the ODEs into one array, say Y[0], ... , Y[39]. Clearly as it is, this makes the whole program painful to read and write. I have to check what Y[i] denotes every time!

So, is there any good way to use alias for these arrays? Also, I am thinking about putting all the system into a class, which makes using reference to the array elements more difficult.

Comment: So... where are the ODEs *before* you drop them into arrays? Would it make more sense to simply use the arrays (or a std::vector<>) as your primary storage rather than wherever your storing them currently?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Currently they are stored just as double variables, which is directly from the equations. like Vm = exp(-dt/tau); activation = inf - activation*(exp(-dt/tau)); (just for example);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an enum for indexes into Y:

```
enum Quantities {
  kDistance,
  kVelocity,
  kAcceleration,
  ...
};
```

Now you can write `Y[kDistance]` everywhere in place of `Y[0]`.

Or, you could define named references for each array element:

```
double Y[40];
double& Distance = Y[0];
double& Velocity = Y[1];
...
```

Now you can write `Distance` everywhere in place of `Y[0]`.

Comment: Thank you. I had thought about using reference to the individual elements of the array. Does this need more memory? And I want to put all the state variables into a class. I have no idea how to do this if using reference, i.e. how to define references for the member variables inside in the class.

Comment: "Does this need more memory?" Probably. I would expect the compiler to represent references as pointers internally. It is possible that, in an optimized build, those references will be optimized away and replaced with array element access, but I doubt it. If that really bothers you, you could use macros, as in `#define Distance (Y[0])`. Personally, I wouldn't worry about 40 pointers' worth of memory overhead, unless you work on a *really* resource-constrained device.

Comment: In a class, a better approach might be an accessor method: `class C { double Y[40]; public: double& Distance() { return Y[0]; } };`. This doesn't have any memory overhead, and all function calls are very likely to be inlined in an optimized build, so it wouldn't have any performance overhead either.

Comment: Thank you. In some cases I may have to simulate more than one million of these systems. So in that case, it maybe better to use the macros.